# order my "products" in DESCENDING order in AS3

Tags: php, actionscript-3, sorting, flash

I've got my AS3 code which is searching into my database and display all the "products" in a list (textfield).

```
function displayPage(pageIndex:int):void {
    list.removeChildren();
    currentPageIndex = pageIndex;
    var firstItemIndex:int = pageIndex * itemsPerPage;
    var j:int = 0;
    var lastItemIndex: int = firstItemIndex + 10; // as lastItemIndex should be 10 more
 if (lastItemIndex > products.length) // if lastindex is greater than products length
 lastItemIndex = products.length;
 for(var i:int = firstItemIndex; i< lastItemIndex; i++){
 createListItem( j, products[i]); // j control the position and i points to particular element of array..
 j++;
 }
}
function complete(e:Event):void {
        loading.visible=false;
    addChild(list);
    products = JSON.parse(loader5.data) as Array;
     products.reverse();
    for(var i:int = 0; i < products.length; i++){
        createListItem(i, products[i]);

}
displayPage(0);
showList();
}

function createListItem(index:int, item:Object):void {

    var listItem:TextField = new TextField();
listItem.text = item.title;

    list.addChild(listItem);
str = item.title;

}
```

In my database I've got a row for "stampTime".

[image]

How can I do to display the products of my list in DESCENDING order (in terms of stampTime, not the first letter of every products) ?

I suppose it must be something like

```
products.sort(Array.DESCENDING);
```

but how to tell AS3 to do descending order BY stampTime (`item.stampTime`) of every products ?

Answer (score 1):

`products.sortOn("stampTime", Array.DESCENDING)`

You can learn for it on [this](https://kapeli.com/dash_share?docset_file=ActionScript&docset_name=ActionScript&path=Array.html%23sortOn()&platform=actionscript&repo=Main&version=3).

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array and evaluate each time stamp in each array element, and if it's the smallest (or largest), push it to a new array. After that loop finishes, your initial array will be empty and your new *temporary* array will be filled in ascending (or descending) order.  Then, loop through the *temporary* array and push them all back into the first array. Now your array is in order based on the time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

The `Array.sort` method is for a basic array.
In your case, the `products` looks like an object array.
You can use `Array.sortOn` method.

```
// sort the stampTime field numerically in descending order
products.sortOn( ["stampTime"], [Array.DESCENDING|Array.NUMERIC]);
```

Maybe your `complete` method is like below.

```
function complete(e:Event):void {
    loading.visible=false;
    addChild(list);
    products = JSON.parse(loader5.data) as Array;

    //products.reverse();
    products.sortOn(["stampTime"], [Array.DESCENDING|Array.NUMERIC]);

    for(var i:int = 0; i < products.length; i++){
        createListItem(i, products[i]);

    }
    displayPage(0);
    showList();
}
```

Read the official document.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fa4.html